# Where to set createParentDirectory function in Mule File connector

Tags: file, mule

I am trying to set the property createParentDirectory in Mule file connector. Unfortunately i am not able to find where to set it. Tried doing it in `<file:connector` and `<file:outbound-endpoint`

Comment: Hi..I am still not able t locate where to configure the property createParentDirectories="true" in Mule. I have tried the connector and the outbound-endpoint. Please suggest..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as below. This is for

```
    <file:copy sourcePath="source.txt"
  targetPath="backup"
  overwrite="true|false"
  createParentDirectories="true|false"
  renameTo="renamed.txt"/>

<file:move sourcePath="source.txt"
  targetPath="backup"
  overwrite="true|false"
  createParentDirectories="true|false"
  renameTo="renamed.txt"/>
```

Please refer to the links ..
[https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/connectivity-dev/anypoint-file-connector-mule-4/][1]

[https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/file-copy-move][2]

Comment: Thanks @kamal but I am still not sure where to configure it. I am not seeing the option to configure it either in file:Connector or file:outbound:endpoint. Could you please guide me where is this option present.